# How do i get date at time in php?

Tags: php, html

I want to get date and time **like**

`17-05-05 at 02:33:15`

how can i write it in `php` please help me is can i use `at` in to `php` **date function**

Comment: Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, just escape the at with backslashes... "You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being expanded by escaping it with a preceding backslash."

Answer (score 0):

Hah 
Finally i got answer from my own mind
we can use `at` in `php` **date function**
`date('y-m-d \a\t h:i:s',time())`

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 1493968008;
$result = date('d-m-Y \a\t H:i:s', $a);
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo date('y-m-d \a\t h:i:s',time()) ?>
```

You have to escape the chars. If you write `a`, date function will understand and show:

> Ante meridiem or Post meridiem

So escape your char like that: `\a`

Ha ve a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT It's done :)